# Cannot read property 'oneOfType' of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I am new to react native. I want to use 'react-native-camera'. I created a new project , installed the package correctly(I know because I have done it thrice to make sure that i'm not doing anything wrong) and it shows this error **Cannot read property 'oneOfType' of undefined ** and it is in index.js of this package 'react-native-camera'. I can't find any solution. I have tried changing gradle version, gradle wrapper properties everything that I could but this issue is not related to gradle. This is the code in my App.js. I know code isn't generating this error but i am new to react-native so maybe i'm missing something.
Any suggestion would be appreciated

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
   import {
   Text,
   View,
  StyleSheet

 } from 'react-native';

 import Camera from 'react-native-camera';

 export default class BarcodeScan extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        qrcode: ''
    }
}

 onBarCodeRead = (e) => this.setState({qrcode: e.data});

 render () {
    return (
        <View  style={styles.container}>
            <Camera
                style={styles.preview}
                onBarCodeRead={this.onBarCodeRead}
                ref={cam => this.camera = cam}
                aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}
                >
                    <Text style={{
                        backgroundColor: 'white'
                    }}>{this.state.qrcode}</Text>
                </Camera>
          </View>
        )
    }

}

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   flexDirection: 'row',
  },
   preview: {
   flex: 1,
   justifyContent: 'flex-end',
   alignItems: 'center'
  }
  });
```

Comment: May I know what "react" and "react-native-camera" version are you using?

Comment: As you have used RCTCamera, please note that since 1.0.0, RCTCamera is deprecated, but if you want to use it, you have use this documentation link https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/RCTCamera.md. Have you made changes according to that link? Please confirm.

Comment: Show me your package.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this guy , https://github.com/dwicao/react-native-panel/issues/4
 I was able to solve this issue by replacing following in index.js of  package 'react-native-camera'.

Replace

```
  import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
```

with

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone finds this thread by searching on the the title (which I did), I will add my experience. Sometimes with TSX, imports get a little weird. What worked for me was using this import:

`import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types'`

I also need to do the same thing with React itself or it does not work either:

`import * as React from 'react'`

So far, these are the only two imports I need to do this for.